# GCP Kubernetes block IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the standard way to block an external IP from accessing my GCP cluster? Happy for the answer to include another Google service.

Comment: Do you plan to block one IP address or thousands? Add more context to your question.

Comment: It was just a single IP. I have now integrated cloud armor in front for of the elb as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your cluster is deployed on Compute Engine instance, you can simply set a firewall rule to discard connection from a specific IP.

If you use an HTTP load balancer, you can add Cloud Armor policy to exclude some IPs.

In both case, keep in mind that IP filtering isn't very efficient. A VPN or Proxy can be easily and freely used on the internet and change the IP source of the requester.

Comment: thanks. i've now implemented cloud armor successfully. i thought that GCP did have a product for it, but for the life of me could not remember it/find it in the dashboard.